# RxJava and Android Service

Tags: android, service, rx-java

I made a simple function test, however I met a strange problem.

The function test is: Starting a service in an activity, then sending message to activity using RxJava and boradcast in the service, at last receiving the message in the activity.

starting service:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, StartIntentService.class);
startService(i);
```

sending message:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Observable.interval(0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .filter(integer -> {
                return (integer < 400) && (integer % 3 == 0);
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(integer -> {
                mIntent.putExtra("num", integer);
                sendBroadcast(mIntent);
            });
}
```

receiving message:

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ACTIVITY_SERVICE_INTERACTIVE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            int res = intent.getIntExtra("num", -1);
            mResTv.append(res + "" + "\t\t\t\t");
        }
    }
}
```

The expected result is: all the numbers can be divisible by 3, however the real result is: all the numbers is -1.

If I replace the method interval with range or I add a method: .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()), everything goes well.

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Observable.interval` emits `Long` values, while in `onReceive` you extract values with `getIntExtra` (instead of `getLongExtra`). So `getIntExtra` returns values you specified as default (`-1`).

`Observable.range` emits `Integer` values, so everything goes as expected.